# How to replace uppercase letters (and rest of word) of string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am working on some javascript that color codes your javascript code by converter text to text with surrounding span element.

I would like to make any word that starts with a capital letter turn gray, using `<span class="gray"> WordWithCapitalLetterAtBeginning </span>`

`Apple()` should turn gray

`APPLE` should turn gray

`bANANA` should not turn gray

`banaNa()` should not turn gray

`orange` should not turn gray

What would I put in a string `replace` in javascript using regex to replace it to the span?

So far I tried: `/([A-Z])/g`, however this only does it with the capital letter, but not the rest of the word.

Here is my js so far:

```
function stylifyCode(s)
{
    s=s.replace('var','<span style="color:blue;">var</span>');
    s=s.replace('\n','<br>')
    s=s.replace(/([A-Z])/g, '<span class="gray">$1</span>')

    return s;
}
```

and when the page is loaded:

```
document.getElementById("mycode").innerHTML = stylifyCode("var hello = 'world!';\nnew Awesome(hello+World())");
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide your HTML? Do you want this check to run for `span` elements only?

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj updated question.

Comment: @gcampbell updated question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean something like the following?

```js
var input = "This is a Test String with some Words in It.";
var output = input.replace(/\b([A-Z]\w*)\b/g, "<span class='gray'>$1</span>");

console.log(output);
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = output;
```

```css
.gray {
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
}
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Explanation: the [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) `\b([A-Z]\w*)\b` matches a word boundary, followed by a capital letter, followed by zero or more word characters, followed by a word boundary.

Comment: Exactly! Thank you. and thanks for the explanation too!

Answer (score 1):

`"new Apple() Test Test, hello".replace(/([A-Z])/g, "<span class='gray'>$1</span>")`

Comment: Getting there, but I would like the whole word to turn gray. I have actually tried that already, forgot to include in my question.